# Nothing gets written to log file (atlassian jira)

Tags: tomcat, log4j, jira

I have installed jira 7.3.6 and made a custom authenticator class where I write the following messages to the log:

```
log.debug(" - - Debug");
log.warn(" - - Warning");
log.info(" - - INFO");
System.out.println("  - - - - -  Test print - - ");
```

but the log file located in:

```
/opt/jira/atlassian/data/log/atlassian-jira.log
```

does not contain any of the above print messages. I do see:

```
- - - - -  Test print - -
```

from the system out call in:

```
/opt/jira/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out
```

which verifies that the above code actually does get executed. The first line in `log4j.properties` contains:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, filelog, cloudAppender
```

so it should print those log messages.

Any ideas what might be wrong and ideas to get the logging to work?

Comment: Did you make your custom authenticator to be compatible with log4j? If yes - you may need to add a lib into JIRA Library folders. Also have you seen https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-configure-logger-in-Jira-plugin/qaq-p/538204 ?

Comment: I am using slf4j-log4j12 which is present in the lib folder. I also have confluence instance running and there it works fine. So I suspect its because of some missing configuration in log4j.properties file or other log configuration xml/files I just don't know where to look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself using:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/logging-and-profiling-802592962.html

The actual location of the file can be read in the Jira Web UI from `System info -> File Paths`